# CSS images different position on different resolutions?

Tags: css, position, resolution, absolute

Ok so i've made a simple webpage with an external CSS, now it appears fine on my computer but when i send it to my friend the bottom buttons are not together?

My Monitor
https://i.stack.imgur.com/juGCv.png

Friends Monitor
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyBOD.png

HTML Code

```
    <body>

<style type="text/css">
body {
    overflow:hidden;     <!-- Setting body overflow to hidden -->
}

<!-- Background image -->



    </style>

    <div id="backgroundWrapper">
        <img src="background.png" />      
    </div>

    <!-- Home button -->   

    <div id="homebtn">
        <a href="..\home.html" onmouseover="SwapOut()" onmouseout="SwapBack()"><img name="homebtn" src="homebuttonup.png"/>   
        </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Shop Button -->

    <div id="shopbtn">
        <a href="shop.html" onmouseover="SwapOutshop()" onmouseout="SwapBackshop()"><img name="shopbtn" src="shopbuttonup.png"/>  
        </a>
    </div>
    </body>
```

CSS Code

```
 #backgroundWrapper{width:100%;height:100%;z-index:-1;position:absolute;}
     #backgroundWrapper img{width:100%;height:100%;z-index:-1; position:absolute;}
     #homebtn {width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1; position:absolute;top:90%; left:35.3%;}
     #shopbtn  {width:100%;height:100%;z-index:1;position:absolute; top:90%; left:50%;}
     #text {
     color:black;
     font-size:15;
     text-align:center;
     position:relative;
     top:20%;
     font-family:verdana;
     font-weight:bold;
     }
     #myform {
    position:absolute;
     left:10%;
     top:30%;

     }


      #submitbuttons {
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
     top:80%;

     }




    body {
     margin-top: 0px;
     margin-right: 0px;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     margin-left: 0px
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `position: absolute;` so you need to wrap the child elements inside a `position: relative;` container so they don't flow out in the wild

For example

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="firstbtn"></div>
   <div class="secondbtn"></div>
</div>

<style>
   .container {
     position: relative;
     height: 200px;
     width: 500px;
   }

   .firstbtn {
     position: absolute;
       left: /* whatever */;
       top: /* whatever */;
   }

   .secondbtn{
     position: absolute;
       left: /* whatever */;
       top: /* whatever */;
   }
</style>
```

So now both button won't flow out of the container element

Comment: @RyanConway what do you mean does this look right? It's obviously right

Comment: @RyanConway Learn CSS positioning, you'll get it why your layout looks awkward on different screen resolutions

Comment: @RyanConwayboth in a single container :) look my code closely

Answer (score 0):

change this css as

```
#backgroundWrapper{width:100%; z-index:-1;position:absolute;}
#backgroundWrapper img{width:100%;height:100%;z-index:-1; position:absolute;}
#button-wrapper{width:30%; margin:0 auto;top:90%;z-index:1;}
#homebtn {position:relative;top:90%;float:left;}
#shopbtn  {float:right;}
```

`#button-wrapper` adjust the width accordingly
create `button-wrapper` and put both btns in html